# Interfacing SD card (R7FS7G27H2A01CBD + e2 studio) - Read/Write issue

Tags: sd-card, renesas-rx

I am encountering difficulties while attempting to interface an SD card with the R7FS7G27H2A01CBD microcontroller using e2 studio.

Please assist me with the proper approach to interface an SD card, as I am a beginner.

I am using Micro SD card adapter and expecting to interface through SPI communication.